# how to assign public ip using JAVAME?

Tags: java-me

i am developing a JavaME application which dynamically assign public ip address given by the server? how to assign public ip to mobile phone using JAVAME?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you want to implement a DHCP client. Perhaps you are better off with running a DHCP service for your network, in which case the details of the IP address assignment will be taken care of by the device's networking software.

JavaME does not provide any APIs for assigning IP adresses to network devices, in fact there are not many generic API sets that provide this functionality.